# rapidjson - change key to another value

Tags: c++, rapidjson

Here is the hello world of rapidjson. How can I change key `"hello"` to `"goodbye"` and get string from the json? I mean I want to parse json, change some keys and get json string back like `{"goodbye" : "world"}`.

```
const char json[] = "{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }";

rapidjson::Document d;
d.Parse<0>(json);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  const char *json = R"({"hello": "world"})";
  rapidjson::Document d;
  d.Parse<0> (json);

  rapidjson::Value::Member* hello = d.FindMember ("hello"); if (hello) {
    d.AddMember ("goodbye", hello->value, d.GetAllocator());
    d.RemoveMember ("hello");
  }

  typedef rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF8<>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>> StringBuffer;
  StringBuffer buf (&d.GetAllocator());
  rapidjson::Writer<StringBuffer> writer (buf, &d.GetAllocator());
  d.Accept (writer);
  json = buf.GetString();
```

P.S. You should probably copy the `json` afterwards because its memory will be freed together with `d`.

P.P.S. You can also replace the field name in-place, without removing it:

```
rapidjson::Value::Member* hello = d.FindMember ("hello");
if (hello) hello->name.SetString ("goodbye", d.GetAllocator());
```

Or during iteration:

```
for (auto it = d.MemberBegin(); it != d.MemberEnd(); ++it)
  if (strcmp (it->name.GetString(), "hello") == 0) it->name.SetString ("goodbye", d.GetAllocator());
```

Comment: What if I iterated and found the member already. I just need to rename the key.

Comment: Updated with in-place examples.

Comment: you use Rapidjson 0.2 right as you have a public `FindMember` method. Where I can find the code for it?

Comment: @Narek, I'm using this repo: https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson. It's been long since I last updated, but from what I see at https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/master/include/rapidjson/document.h the `FindMember` still seems to be public. What version are you using?

Comment: the one that comes with cocos2d-x latest version which should be 0.11 where `FindMember` is not a public method.

Answer (score 3):

In my case there is a key dictionary named `keyDict` which stores the values that object keys should be replaced with.

```
std::string line;
std::map<std::string, int>  keyDict;

.....................
.........................

rapidjson::Document         doc;
doc.Parse<0>(line.c_str());
rapidjson::Value::MemberIterator itr;


for (itr = doc.MemberonBegin(); itr != doc.MemberonEnd(); ++itr)
{
    std::string keyCode = std::to_string(keyDict[itr->name.GetString()]);
    itr->name.SetString(keyCode.c_str(), keyCode.size(), doc.GetAllocator());
}
```

Comment: It is a question. I have asked, you answered me, but then I have figured out this way, and wanted to check if it is OK or not. Thanks for you answeres.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight as you could note my answer is a complete answer too. And I undeleted my post as far I have a case ArtemGr does not. I mean when you set string using not literals, but local variable.